# Angularjs splitChunks $injector:modulerr error

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I'm trying to configure splitChunks for my application, but when I build, I get an error [$injector:modulerr](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr)

webpack.config

```
    const result = {

        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.ts$/,
                    exclude: [ /node_modules/ ],
                    use: [
                        'ng-annotate-loader',
                        'awesome-typescript-loader'
                    ]
                },
            ]
        },
       optimization: {
            runtimeChunk: true,
            splitChunks: {
                chunks: 'all',
                maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
                minSize: 
            },

        },
        plugins: [
            new ExtractTextPlugin({
                // filename: './css/style.bundle.css',
                allChunks: true,
            }),
            new ngAnnotatePlugin({
                add: true,
            }),
        ],
    };
    return result;
}

module.exports = getConfig(NODE_ENV);
```

app.ts

```
function getModulesName() {
    return [
        'ngAnimate',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'ngResource',
        'ngSanitize',
        'ui.router',
        'pascalprecht.translate',
        'ngMessages',
        'LocalStorageModule',
        'toaster',
    ];
    const coreApp = angular.module(coreAppName, getModulesName());

....

coreApp.run([
        '$http',
        'authenticationService',
        '$state',
        '$rootScope',
        '$log',
        ($http: IHttpService, authenticationService: AuthenticationService, $state, $rootScope, $log) => {}
.config(stateConfig)
....
}
```

state.config

```
export function stateConfig($stateProvider: ng.ui.IStateProvider,
                            $urlRouterProvider: any,
                            $locationProvider: ILocationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider
        .when(...)
        .otherwise(...);

$stateProvider
        .state(...)
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}

stateConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider'];
```

as far as I understand it is connected with the application build feature of the webpack and the injector does not work correctly, but I don’t know how to solve this error

please help with this error

Comment: This error occurs when a module fails to load due to some exception. The error message above should provide additional context.

A common reason why the module fails to load is that you've forgotten to include the file with the defined module or that the file couldn't be loaded.

Comment: @georgeawg this error appears only if enable splitChunks:{chunks: 'all'}

Comment: Did you ever solve this @se3os?